# Roku (Brightscript) - Playing DRM Protected Video Content

Tags: drm, roku, brightscript, widevine, playready

These is a self answering question.

Problem:
Can not play videos which are protected by PlayReady DRM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working sample

```
    if m.VideoPlayer = invalid
        m.VideoPlayer = m.top.createChild("Video")
        m.VideoPlayer.id = "VideoPlayer"
        m.VideoPlayer.observeField("state", "OnVideoStateChange")
    end if
    drmParams = {}

    videoContent = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
    videoContent.Live = remoteContent.IsLive
    videoContent.Url = remoteContent.Path

    if remoteContent.CodecType = "DashWideVineDrm" then
        videoContent.StreamFormat = "dash"
        drmparams.licenseServerURL = remoteContent.DrmRightsUrl
        drmParams.KeySystem = "widevine"
    else if remoteContent.CodecType = "PlayReadyDrm" then
        videoContent.StreamFormat = "ism"
        drmParams.KeySystem = "playready"
        drmParams.encodingType = "PlayReadyLicenseAcquisitionUrl"
        drmParams.encodingKey = remoteContent.DrmRightsUrl
    else
        videoContent.StreamFormat = "mp4"
    end if
    videoContent.drmParams = drmParams

    device = CreateObject("roDeviceInfo")

    httpAgent = CreateObject("roHttpAgent")
    if httpAgent <> invalid then
        httpAgent.SetCertificatesFile("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt")
        httpAgent.InitClientCertificates()
        httpAgent.EnableCookies()
        httpAgent.AddHeader("X-Roku-Reserved-Dev-Id", "")
        if remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER1 <> invalid and remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER1 <> "" then 
            httpAgent.AddHeader("MY-CUSTOM-HEADER2", remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER1)
        end if
        if remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER2 <> invalid and remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER2 <> "" then 
            httpAgent.AddHeader("MY-CUSTOM-HEADER2", remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER2)
        end if
        m.VideoPlayer.setHttpAgent(httpAgent)
    else
        headers = []
        headers.push("X-Roku-Reserved-Dev-Id:")
        if remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER1 <> invalid and remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER1 <> "" then headers.push("MY-CUSTOM-HEADER1:" + remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER1)
        if remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER2 <> invalid and remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER2 <> "" then headers.push("MY-CUSTOM-HEADER2:" + remoteContent.MYCUSTOMHEADER2)
        videoContent.HttpHeaders = headers
        videoContent.HttpSendClientCertificates = true
        videoContent.HttpCertificatesFile = "common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
        m.VideoPlayer.EnableCookies()
        m.VideoPlayer.SetCertificatesFile("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt")
        m.VideoPlayer.InitClientCertificates()
    end if

    m.VideoPlayer.content = videoContent
    m.VideoPlayer.control = "play"
```

NOTE:
If you use PlayReady DO NOT FILL drmParams.licenseServerURL, because it will fail to play with DRM Error (-6).